# Amazon SES bounce handling in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I've read those articles about handling bounces:
[Amazon SES Notifications Through Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications-via-sns.html)

[Using Notifications with Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html)

[Testing Amazon SES Email Sending](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html)

[Amazon SES Bounce FAQ](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/e-faq-bn.html)

But I still can't understand how to create controller function, which will delete bounced emails from dispatch list using Symfony2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [AWS SES Monitor Bundle](http://github.com/Aerendir/aws-ses-monitor-bundle) that can do for you all the needed stuff.

It can setup topics on AWS SNS and subscribe your AWS SES to them to get notifications about bounces, complaints and deliveries.

It includes a SwiftMailer filter that permits you to not send emails to bounced or complained emails.

Comment: the link is dead, at least for me.